# sandwich theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does sandwich theorem hold for divergent sequences?
Given a divergent sequence $\{v_n\},$ can we find 2 sequences $\{u_n\}$ and $\{w_n\},$ such that $$\{u_n\} < \{v_n\} < \{w_n\},$$ and if $\{u_n\}$ and $\{w_n\}$ diverges to L = ±∞,  then can we conclude $\{v_n\}$ also diverges to L = ±∞?

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence to "diverge to $L$"?

Comment: here L is not finite.  But my question is does the theorem hold for divergent sequences? 
1) I cant compare oscillatory sequences since they diverging to two different points
2) but if i take {un},{vn} and {wn} as properly divergent sequences then it seems to hold
3) same thing for unbounded above or unbounded below sequences

Comment: You do realize that there are bounded divergent sequences? Sequences that don't go to infinity but still diverge?

Comment: It's easier than that.  All you need is one series that diverges to infinity less than your given series, or one that diverges to negative infinity greater than your given series.  No need to squeeze something if it is being shoved off to infinite values already with one bound.

Comment: yes @DonThousand, oscillating finitely sequences are bounded , but still diverge. But I cant consider such sequences for comparison. It must diverge either to positive infinity or negative infinity

Comment: @RobertTheTutor,  ya correct. That makes sense for unbounded above and unbounded below sequences. However for oscillating finitely, oscillating infinitely sequences it doesn't hold. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If you know $w_n-u_n\to 0$ and $w_n$ diverges, then $u_n$ and $v_n$ both diverge. But it is unclear what you mean by “diverges to $L.$” If that just means “does not converge to $L,$” you can let $u_n=L-1, v_n=L, w_n=L+1$ for all $n.$

Comment: The question makes no sense and needs to be edited.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I can't let Un and Wn have different limits. It violates the theorem

Comment: I’m trying to figure out what you mean by “diverges to $L.$” That is non-standard terminology. If you mean “both converge $+\infty$ or both to $-\infty,$” then say that, or at least add to your question “where $L=\pm \infty.$” In any even, you only need $u_n\to +\infty$ to get $v_n\to +\infty.$ And you only need $w_n\to-\infty$ to conclude that $v_n\to -\infty.$

Comment: Now is it fine @ThomasAndrews?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really only need $u_n\to+\infty$ to conclude that $v_n\to+\infty.$

You only need $w_n\to-\infty$ to conclude that $v_n\to -\infty.$

However, if you only know that $u_n$ and $w_n$ both converge to the same $L=\pm \infty,$ without knowing whether it is $+\infty$ or $-\infty,$ then I suppose you need that they go to the same infinity to show that $v_n$ goes to the same infinity.

In terms of usefulness in specific proofs, you’ll usually know roughly what direction you are going in, so you won’t need both.

---

And for other divergent sequences, which don’t go to either infinity, you can prove divergence by finding $u_n,w_n$ such that one of $u_n$ and $w_n$ is known to be divergent, and $w_n-u_n\to 0.$

That’s actually the true generalization to the squeeze theorem. If $u_n\to L, w_n\to L$ where $L\in\mathbb R,$ then $w_n-u_n\to 0.$

So you can say that, if $w_n-u_n\to 0,$ and $v_n$ is between them, then $v_n$  converges if and only if at least one of $u_n$ or $w_n$ converges.

Comment: " However, if you only know that un and wn both converge to the same L=±∞, without knowing whether it is +∞ or −∞, then I suppose you need that they go to,the same infinity to show that un goes to the same infinity. " 
Here do you mean un and wn , or un and vn? Could you kindly explain this paragraph more clearly?

Comment: Meant $v_n.$ Fixed

Comment: Thankyou very much

Answer (score 1):

No and Yes. Answer depends on whether they diverge one to $-\infty$ and one to $\infty$;
both to $-\infty$; or both to $\infty$.

1. No

Sandwich theorem  for diverging sequences

Given three sequences  $u_n < v_n < w_n$,

suppose $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}w_n= \infty$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}u_n= -\infty$, then $v_n$ also diverges.

False, here is a counter example:

Consider three sequences $u_n < v_n < w_n$

\begin{array}{c|rrrrrr}
\text{sequence} & \text{values} & & \\
\hline
w_n & 1, & 2, & 3, & 4, & 5,&\ldots \\
u_n & -1, & -2, & -3, & -4, & -5,&\ldots \\
v_n & 0, & 0, & 0, & 0, & 0, &\ldots
\end{array}

Clearly $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}w_n= \infty$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}u_n= -\infty$, both diverge, But $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}v_n=0$.

Even though $v_n$ is sandwiched between two divergent sequences, $v_n$ can still converge!

2. Yes.

Given three sequences  un < vn < wn,

Sandwich theorem  for diverging sequences

2a. suppose wn--> ∞, un--> ∞, then vn --> ∞.

2b. suppose un-->-∞  un-->-∞, then vn -->-∞.

Q for Don:

1. How do I format the following Fourier Transform for x(t)

$$X(jw) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty x(t) \exp(-jwt)\:dt\tag{*}$$

2. How do I sum the following Laurent series

$$f(x) = 1 - \frac1{3 x^2} + \frac1{5 x^4} - \frac1{7 x^6} + O\left(x^{-7}\right)$$

3. lim_x->∞ f(x) =0

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest using mathjax to make your answers look better.

Comment: I am not familiar with Mathjax and have just started to use it.  Needless  to say, it is not easy for a beginner.  I'll try to make it better though.  Thanks.

Comment: take a look at the other answer. I learned mathjax by copying other users when I was first starting.

Comment: Sure. the problem is I often get a syntax error. It often happened that no warning is given.  Even if it gives warning, they don't tell you how to correct it. The manual helps but to certain extent. And you have to learn it thru repeated trial and error.  Do you know if there is more detailed manual available for beginners?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: And if you want to debug, it's not a bad idea to write basic LaTeX math mode code in some TeX compiler (which is what MathJax essentially is), and then port it here.

Comment: I have some trouble with my equation and its label. I don't know how to add spaces in between as mathjax has its own mind.  And how do you separate the integrand from its upper and lower limit. Similarly for sigma sign and its index and summand. How do you insert x->0 below the lim, not a subscript. etc.

Comment: I'll fix up your answer, hopefully that helps. For separating, after a \sum, \prod,\int, etc, using \limits_{lower limit}^{upper limit} separates the limits from the contents.

Comment: Great.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @cdaemaze I did one section, since I was too lazy to do more. Enjoy

Comment: Thanks for your great effort. Now can you help me solve the spacing problem of equation for Fourier transform X(jw) = int_0^

Comment: which one? I don't see an equation

Comment: I'm working on it.  Bear with me for a moment as I am NOT a good typist. :)

Comment: Fourier transform X(jw) = int_-∞^ ∞  x(t) exp(-jwt)dt {4spaces}  (*)where do I need $ where do I need \and where do I add space in between. Where do I need $$as opposed to $and how do you bold some part but not the other part.  How do you avoid all the words closedly  packed such as "nospaceinbetween".
Another problem is sum(i= 1 to m)sum(j= 1 to n) sum(k =1 to K) aij=sum(aik*bkj)/π 1
and place function ln(x) inside another function √ how do you get the sqrt sign to extend to the right so that I can squeeze in a ln(x).

Sorry, I created a lot of work for you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put it in your answer so I can edit it

Comment: OK, Don.  Please see my question in my answer near the bottom.  Thanks

Comment: Got it.  Thanks again, Don. You make my days brighter! :)